# Schtasks.exe 100% cpu usage

Tags: windows

We have two old virtualmachine 2008 r2, running remote desktop app services, and we got some issues with  schtask.exe process that comes randomly and uses all of cpu ressources that freeze the server.

We have to force restart the vm to get the services running again.

My question :

is it possible to disable remote access to schtasks.exe? Because we 're suspecting a virus trying to remotly access to the task scheduler on both machines.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -1):

We are having the same exact issue (CPU usage @ 100% pinned, caused by schtask.exe.)

There is nothing new with this server, except Windows Updates.

I went into resource monitor and suspended schtask.exe for now until I can identify what the issue is. It brought CPU usage back down to 4%.

Comment: Thank you. 
How did you manage to stop schtask being executed?
I just took ownership and renamed the schtasks.exe I. System 32

Comment: I moved schtasks.exe out of SYS32 directory, and it stopped running while I figure out what is happening.